# how to display the most recent record in a database mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created a table full of DVDs that have the Year of release column (YOR)

My query is that I want the database to give me the most recent "Action" DVD on the year it was released

I started with:

```
SELECT * from DVD where YOR by Genre ASCE LIMIT 1;
```

This command I used gave me the most recent DVD that was released but it wasn't an action DVD

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your genre a String? SELECT * from DVD where Genre = 'Action' order by YOR DESC LIMIT 1;

Comment: yeah, your answer was correct and it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * from DVD
WHERE Genre = 'Action'
ORDER BY YOR DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You'll probably have to tweak it depending on the datatype of `Genre` and what values are in there.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM DVD 
WHERE Genre = 'Action'
ORDER BY YOR DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is a repeat of Vland's answer.